# Persisting classes in JPA: Creating an abstract superclass with @id, using @EmbeddedId, or more: pros and cons

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, relational-database, uniqueidentifier

Recently, I have been thinking about a way to model the concept of primary key of the relational databases. In such model, every relation (table) has its own. All tables, but "join tables", have their own field(s). In my experience, most of the times it is an "Auto increment" integer field, which totally makes sense when it does not have to have a specific semantic at "Application level".

In the object-oriented model, we have several ways to manage the issue of assigning an ID, so that entity objects can be persisted. JPA allows for the @Id Annotation, but it also allows to use @EmbeddedId, so that one can create an ID class and embed it into any object to be persisted.

In my experience, I found pretty fast the use of an abstract super class IdentifiableEntity, which has an @Id Long id.
Any other class, rather than extending Object, extends this class or another class which is in the subhierarchy of IdentifiableEntity.
Using the inheritance strategy TABLE_PER_CLASS (and generally leveraging Spring Data), this turns into a single ID counter shared among all classes, so that any object to persist gets a unique ID into the entire system. 
This may work for small projects, e.g. when such IdentifiableEntity has its own set of relationships to other classes.

An alternative would be to put an @Id field into any subtree of IdentifiableEntity, i.e. I could just replicate the id-related code (including the inheritance strategy to map classes to tables). I don't like this: I am replicating code, which I really don't like when it is a matter of configuration. However, when it does not make sense having a unique parent (i.e. IdentifiableEntity), this is the solution I adopt. This may work also for large projects.
A more appropriate solution could be having one @MappedSuperclass with such id field and then having all other subtrees rooted in such class. This way, no shared ID in the relational model, but still no replicated code.

What solution(s) do you generally use? What pros and cons you think exist with the possible solutions?

Comment: An inheritance strategy is not the tool to use for this. You should use `@MappedSuperclass`. There is no reason for the IDs to be unique among all the entities. And there is no reason for a User and an OrderLine to have a common parent entity.

Comment: It seems you haven't. Don't ever user `@Inheritance` to do this. Use `@MappedSuperclass`. That's what it's for.

Comment: Inheritance exists as a solution and it does make sense in the OO model. In general, it may happen that IdentifiableEntity has its own set of relationships, so it would make sense for it to exist. The limit I see is in the mapping to the relational model: you write more (configuration) replicated code and get the correct relational model. I write less code and may get an incorrect relational model. It's a matter of point of view.

Comment: `@MappedSuperclass` is about using inheritance. Have you at least read the javadoc? The difference with `@Inheritance` is that it's about *code* and *mapping* inheritance, instead of being about *entity* inheritance. A User and an OrderLine have nothing in common, except they both share a Long ID mapped to a column named ID. That's code inheritance, and that's what MappedSuperclass allows

Comment: I believe your vision is somewhat extreme. What if I need to query the IdentifiableEntity? Using @MappedSuperclass will prevent me from doing so. On the other side, the simple fact that User and OrderLine share a syntactically identical field mapped to a syntactically identical column is a good reason in OO to create a common class holding it. In the OO model, in fact, I can use my business logic to avoid sharing the same "id bucket". So the point is that I don't have a tool to "explain" to the ORMs that the two IDs are different (unless I give up something and use @MappedSuperclass)

Comment: Why would you ever do that? Have you ever had to write a query that returns Users and OrderLines in the same collection? No, because they have absolutely nothing in common. You could write a query returning Workers and Managers in the same collection, and that's where Inheritance is useful. and I repeat, once again: MappedSuperclass is about using inheritance. You can, and should, define your ID column and mapping in a base class annotated with MappedSuperclass. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that one could have one MappedSuperclass IdentifiableEntity with the ID and then a number of hierarchies, possibly all rooted in such MappedSuperclass IdentifiableEntity, each defining its own Inheritance?

Comment: Yes, except it's quite rare to actually need entity inheritance. So most hierarchies would contain a single entity.